# require() to import throws error: Cannot read property 'createsocket' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

When I use require the import works correctly:

`let dgram = require('react-native-udp')`

But when I try to use the same as import:

`import dgram from 'react-native-udp'`

I get error: `Cannot read property 'createsocket' of undefined`

When I look inside its dir in node_modules this is what I get:

[image]

I also tried:

```
  import {dgram} from 'react-native-udp'
```

But get same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
import * as dgram from 'react-native-udp'
```

Comment: A little explanation about why this works and the other didn't would make your answer more useful to other readers.

Comment: Actually I don't know :) I just know it's equivalent to `let dgram = require('react-native-udp')` and then you can use `dgram`.